# How to inject the value coming from a rule into a test spring context?

Tags: spring, testing, junit, spring-test, junit-rule

suppose you have the following situation while testing a spring context

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ConfigClass.class})
public class IntegrationTest   {

 @ClassRule 
 static PluginThatSetsUpSomethingEmbedded pluginRule = new PluginThatSetsUpSomethingEmbedded();



}
```

now one of my Spring beans needs something that can only come out of the rule, like:

```
pluginRule.getEmbeddedToolConfig()
```

how can I provide my bean with that config, notice that the rule is ClassRule and is static too...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [ApplicationContextInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html) and your test class will be something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ConfigClass.class}, initializers = IntegrationTest.Initializer.class)
public class IntegrationTest   {

 @ClassRule 
 static PluginThatSetsUpSomethingEmbedded pluginRule = new PluginThatSetsUpSomethingEmbedded();

 public static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
    }


}
```

And in method initialize you can implement your logic.